Automorphism groups for simple objects in abelian linear categories
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category that is also $k$-linear, where $k$ is some algebraically closed field. Let $X$ be a simple object in $\mathcal{A}$. What can we say about $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$? I mean it is a subgroup of the ring $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$, but perhaps we can say more because of simplicity . . . ?
Edit: Will $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$ ever be finite-dimensional over $k$?

The endomorphisms of $X$ form a division ring with $k$ in its centre (Schur's Lemma), and the automorphisms are just the multiplicative group of non-zero elements therein.

Why are the non-zero elements always invertible?

Otherwise the kernel and image are proper subobjects.

In your edit, that's the other part of Schur's Lemma. If $k$ is algebraically closed then division rings that are finite dimensional over $k$ are equal to $k$.

Thanks for the comments! So the key is Schur's lemma for abelian categories. I found some nice notes here: https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~jjs435/garts/Tamar%20April%202021%20annotated.pdf
